# parse error (possibly incorrect indentation)

Tags: haskell

when i execute the following lines of code i get the following error

```
TyInfer.hs:115:0: parse error (possibly incorrect indentation)
```

can anyone explain me what is the problem.

```
  type Subst = [(TyVar, Type)]

  -- ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Unification
  --
  unify :: Type -> Type -> Subst
  unify t1 t2 = error "substBnd: implement me"
   -- ---------------------------------------------------------------------
   -- Replace variables in the type with the types in the Subst
   --
  line: no 115: substitute :: Subst -> Type -> Type
   substitute [( _ , t2)] tv = tv <- t2
  -- ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Replace variables in the type annotations of a Bind, Expr, or Alt
  --
  substBnd :: Subst -> Bind -> Bind
  substBnd _ _ = error "substBnd: implement me"
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is the whole thing actually indented 2 or 3 spaces?

Comment: Your top level definitions should not be indented. Also, `tv <- t2` is not valid syntax.

Comment: What is the intended function of substitute? Your comment is sort of unclear.

Comment: @JeffreyBurka I'm guessing type substitution from his comments and general problem. e.g. replace all free occurences of TyVar in tv with the Type in tv while avoiding new captures.

Answer (score 1):

The lines defining `substitute` are indented more than the lines defining other values. Unindent them.

Answer (score 1):

The indentation of substitute as well as its definition are not correct . tv<-t2 does not make any sense . please be more clear what you intend to do with the substitute function.